# TSQL how to remove all characters or text after the last tab space

Tags: t-sql

I have some data that look like this:

```
Maple Leaf City
```

This is all in a single column called City.

I want to remove the word City so that the output looks like this:

```
Maple Leaf
```

My code below removes the everything after the first space instead of the last.

How do I take this: `Maple Leaf City` and turn it into `Maple Leaf`?

This is what I have got:

```
SELECT LEFT(City, CHARINDEX(' ', City) - 1)
FROM MyTable
WHERE CHARINDEX(' ', City) > 1
```

My code gives me this: `Maple`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
declare @str varchar(255)
set @str = 'Maple Leaf City'
select LEFT(@str, LEN(@str) - CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(@str)))
```